# Python - Insert a decorator inside an already decorated function

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I've researched quite a bit on this but wasn't able to find an answer for it. I basically have an existing function, func1, which is decorated by my_dec1. my_dec1 takes in arguments as

```
func1.py

@my_dec1(a, b)
def func1():
...
```

I have another decorator, my_dec2, and want to stack my decorators by inserting my_dec2 before my_dec1. So the end result would achieve the same functionality as below:

```
main.py

@my_dec1(a, b)
@my_dec2
def func1():
...
```

My question is that only given func1, am I able to extract my_dec1 and save it to some variable? If not, can I extract the parameters passed to my_dec1 to recreate the decorator again?

However, the challenging part now is that I want to do this without being able to modify any of the original source code in func1.py.

```
main.py

import func1

unwrapped_func = func1.__wrapped__ # returns undecorated func1

??? # do something here to extract my_dec1 functionality from func1

final = my_dec1(a, b)(my_dec2(unwrapped_func))
final()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. There is no stack of decorators associated with a function; recall that:

```
@my_decorator
def somefunc():
  ...
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
def somefunc():
  ...


somefunc = my_decorator(somefunc)
```

Given the function name `somefunc`, in neither case is there any way to figure out "the original function" in order to inject a decorator "earlier" in the stack.